# Conditional formatting on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm new to Google Sheets, and I'm looking to get my C5 cell filled with green if its value is equal to my A5 cell's value.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: And, is there a way to do it for the entire column? Like C5 equal with A5, C6 equal with A6, C7 equal with A7, etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Right click** on any cell in column C and then **left click** on **conditional formatting**. Choose the settings exactly as you see in the following screenshot and use the following custom formula:

```
=AND(C1=A1,C1<>"")
```

[image: explanation]

Comment: It said "Invalid formula", but it worked whit just =AND(C1=A1).
Thanks a lot :) Can you help me with the same formula but to make C3 filled with red when different from A3 please? Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: @user3507621 just add another conditional formatting rule for the same column and create a custom formula C3<>A3 and choose color red.