# How to use conditional formatting on a whole column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need some help with my Google Sheets guys. I want to know if there's a fast way to set conditional formatting on a whole column, like when I drag it down or copy and paste my rule "=AND(A1=B1)" to the line under to automatically turn in into "=AND(A2=B2)"?

Hope you guys can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional formatting on Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64089486/conditional-formatting-on-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution, it's just by adding a $ like this : "=AND($A1=$B1)"